# Unexpected template string expression no-template-curly-in-string

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React from 'react'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import {Row,Col,Image,ListGroup,Card,Button} from 'react-bootstrap'
import Rating from '../components/Rating'
import products from '../products'

const ProductScreen = ({match}) => {
    const product=products.find(p=> p._id=match.params.id)
    
    return (
        <>
           <Link className='btn btn-light my-3'to= '/'>Go Back</Link>
           <Row>
               <Col md ={6}>
                   <Image src={product.image} alt={product.name} fluid/>
               </Col>
               <Col md ={3}>
                     <ListGroup variant='flush'>
                         <ListGroup.Item>
                             <h3>
                                 {product.name}
                             </h3>
                         </ListGroup.Item>
                         <ListGroup.Item>
                             <Rating value={product.rating} text={'${product.numReviews}reviews'}/>
                         </ListGroup.Item>
                         <ListGroup.Item>
                             price: ${product.price}
                         </ListGroup.Item>
                         <ListGroup.Item>
                             Description: {product.description}
                         </ListGroup.Item>
                     </ListGroup>
               </Col>

              <Col md={3}>
                  <Card>
                      <ListGroup variant='flush'>
                          <ListGroup.Item>
                              <Row>
                                  <Col>
                                  Price:
                                  </Col>
                                  <Col>
    <strong>${product.price}</strong>
                                  </Col>
                              </Row>
                          </ListGroup.Item>
                          <ListGroup.Item>

                          <Row>
                                  <Col>
                                  Status:
                                  </Col>
                                  <Col>
    {product.countInStock > 0 ?'In stock': 'Out of Stock'}
                                  </Col>
                              </Row>
                          </ListGroup.Item>

                          <ListGroup.Item>
                              <Button className='btn-block' type='button' disabled={product.countInStock === 0}
                              >
                                  Add To Cart
                              </Button>
                          </ListGroup.Item>
                      </ListGroup>
                  </Card>
              </Col>
           </Row>
        </>
    )
}

export default ProductScreen
```

Comment: You want \`${product.numReviews}reviews\` with the back tick, not a single quote.

Comment: thankyou, this solved my error

Comment: Hi, also here p=> p._id=match.params.id, I think you are missing ===, p=> p._id===match.params.id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use backtick(`string template literal`) instead of single quote, Try like below

```
<Rating value={product.rating} text={`${product.numReviews}reviews`}/>
```

Comment: @Anas if answer is resolved problem, please accept the answer.